# How to sync Surfingkeys settings

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, browser, browser-addons, web

What's the best way to sync Surfingkeys settings?

I've found [Surfingkeys](https://github.com/brookhong/Surfingkeys) to be the best vim shortcut key extension for all browsers.  It works amazing on every one that I've tried.  However, it claims to "Sync across devices", so maybe I'm just not doing something right.

The following look like bugs to me, but also explain what I've tried so far:

- There is no sync-settings button or service in Chrome extension settings, regardless if 'Advanced Mode' is checked or not.
- I couldn't export settings in Chrome.  Now I can't find where I found to do this, but it gives me console errors:
  Chrome 121.0.6167.160 x86_64 on Mac 13.6.7 did not allow me to export settings with:

```
Surfingkeys.config.exportToFile('/Users/me/surfingkeys.json')
```

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Surfingkeys is not defined
```

How does one show what objects are available in Chrome dev console? This seems to say 'Surfingkeys.' should be available, but I notice there is nothing offered via tab-completion, so I'm sure it's just not there.

- I notice Safari has a bug with a workaround:
  https://github.com/brookhong/Surfingkeys/discussions/1790

```
document.getElementById("localPathForSettings").style.display = ""
```

- Some Surfingkeys doc suggested I use ACE editor.  Is that able to export settings?  I couldn't figure out if that's what is being used by default:
  https://github.com/brookhong/Surfingkeys/issues/2
- Chromium on Ubuntu doesn't allow me to 'Allow access to file URL's' at all.  If this is already known by Surfingkeys devs, it should be documented.
- Firefox does not allow you to export or import settings.  At least this is a [known bug](https://github.com/brookhong/Surfingkeys/pull/891).

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible solution, hope someone can suggest a better one:

1. Open the configured browser's plugin settings, by clicking on Surfingkeys extension icon > Settings.
2. Select all text.  If in advanced mode, click the text area and:

```
gg V G
```

3. Save to workstation clipboard:

```
"0y
```

4. Open a new file and paste contents into it.
5. Manually move this file to other workstations, and do the same procedure, in reverse, to paste it in.

Answer (score 0):

Another incomplete solution: Use each browser's plugin sync capabilities.

Google Chrome's plugin sync takes care of the sync'ing of these settings 100%. The problem I had was Chromium in Linux wasn't syncing, but that's a different issue.